# Mac compiler on windows

Tags: windows, macos, compiler-construction, cross-platform, cross-compiling

Is it possible to develop cross-platform application on Windows and can also compile for Mac OS X from Windows? I have checked Qt but that requires one to compile from Mac using Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your priority then one option would be Java as at least a jar file built on one platform can be run on another.

If however you're talking about C or C++...

If you are creating a small command line tool then you *might* be able to make this work with gcc and a cross compiler, but I think it would be a lot of work.

If however you are wanting to create a GUI application I would urge you to give up now. There are so many issues - you'd have to use Carbon or Cocoa APIs which you can't build for on any other platform, you'd have to link against frameworks which won't exist on your compilation host, you won't be able to easily generate .plist files.  Qt won't help as you need to be able to build it, which relies on these same frameworks.

In short, there's no alternative to building on an actual mac.

Furthermore, when it comes to fixing bugs, you will absolutely have to do this on a mac (either physical or virtual).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I was also thinking that instead of creating GUI based application for cross-platform its better to develop it in platform native language. I have checked some cross-platform framework Qt, Mono; both require to compile on Mac and also they have many known issues which I think will be difficult to handle after the development.

Comment: Is there any hosting solution that offer mac os system online, so I can use xcode virtually or any other similar solution for using xcode virtually?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's possible to run Mac OS in a virtual machine, but AFAIK it's against the terms of the OSX licence to do so.  If you really need to build for OSX then there really is no alternative than to buy a Mac. There's all sorts of issues with installation, compatibility bugs with different OS versions, etc that are impossible to deal with if you don't have access to a physical machine.

Comment: Just thought to share it with you, I have found macincloud.com after searching on net, which provide mac osx on hourly basis with different development softwares like xcode, monomac. They have different packages with 1st day as a free trial.

Comment: Interesting idea - I guess that could work out cheaper if you needed to test on a number of different systems. I think it would only be viable though if your application was very simple and quick to build.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know , in general you do need a mac to make the executable , even for a simple ansi c program you need gcc for mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [MacPorts](http://guide.macports.org/) [Portfile](http://guide.macports.org/#development.introduction).(If your application is open source)

> A MacPorts port is a set of specifications contained in a Portfile
>   that defines an application, its characteristics, and any files or
>   special instructions required to install it. This allows you to use a
>   single command to tell MacPorts to automatically download, compile,
>   and install applications and libraries.

Take a look at [IMCROSS](http://www.sandroid.org/imcross/).

> IMCROSS is a simple, scripted method of installing cross-compilers and
>   cross-compiled libraries on a Linux (or possibly other *nix) system,
>   so that you can develop programs targeted to run on Microsoft Windows
>   and Mac OS X at the same time and in the same environment as you
>   develop Linux versions of those programs.

Comment: Thanks, I will check them in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this using [Real Studio](http://www.realstudio.com).  It can create Mac OS X applications on Windows without any trouble.

It cross-compiles for Windows, OS X and Linux.  And it does it from any platform.  It also can create web apps.

Sounds like you should check it out.